# How to initialize bootstrap-classify?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, underscore.js, single-page-application

I am trying to make a simple static page that uses this [bootstrap-classify](https://github.com/aml-development/bootstrap-classify) library. I tried looking at several pieces of its code for hints on how to implement it. I'm pretty sure at least one step needed is to add `.bs-classify` to an HTML element but so far I haven't gotten anything useful to happen. I don't have any errors on the js console and all resources are loading without issues.

**Below is a snippet of what is in index.html**

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js" integrity="sha256-G7A4JrJjJlFqP0yamznwPjAApIKPkadeHfyIwiaa9e0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="js/ism-u.config.js"></script>
<script src="js/ism.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-classify.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap-classify.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Create an issue on the Github page. Ask the author. No one have time for bad documented project.

Comment: I don't even bother to use a plugin if there's no documentation for it. So, while there may be people on here that can help, it is probably only a select few. I suggest asking the creator of the plugin or find something more useful to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is just to give you something to start with. I didn't thoroughly go through the bs-classify library code. Thus, I assume there is a lot more to that code. I just don't understand why that code is not documented.

Nonetheless, the method below is simple. It just constructs a classified object with minimal configuration. You would need to read through the options of the code to understand what options the code has.

Besides that, you would have to figure out how to set the classification using options, as I couldn't figure out why that does not work. I left that in the constructor so you have something to look at. Nonetheless, the real classification setter code in the answer is the .setClassification() statement.

Also, I did not try to use the Plugin API.

For the code below, you can try clicking on the Primary button.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-classify.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js" integrity="sha256-G7A4JrJjJlFqP0yamznwPjAApIKPkadeHfyIwiaa9e0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="js/ism-u.config.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ism.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-classify.js"></script>
  <script>
      window.onload = function() {
          var abc = new $.fn.classify.Constructor(document.getElementById("test-1"),
                                                            {classification: ['TS'],
                                                             title: "Classification Box",
                                                             mode: "modal"});
          console.log(abc.getClassification());
          abc.setClassification("TS");
          console.log(abc.getClassification());
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="test-1">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through their source code and trying to reverse engineer it, it looks like you want:

```js
$.fn.classify
```

or

```js
$.fn.classify.Constructor
```

If this turns out not to be the case, then let me know and I will try to update this answer.

For `$.fn.classify` the only parameter is an options object, which has the following possible properties:

- format - can be either "bl" or "pm"
- without - probably boolean
- input - probably boolean
- relto - looks like boolean
- fgi - looks like boolean
- mode - can be "modal"
- title - most likely a string (a title)
- container
- viewport
- selector - looks like a queryselector
- headings
- nonic
- btnsize
- trigraphs
- tetragraphs
- update
- callback - most likely a function
- fdr - boolean